# Convergence of series with logarithms and square roots

Tags: sequences-and-series

**I. $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \ln \left(1 + \frac{1}{n^2}\right)$**

**II. $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left( \sqrt{n^3} - \sqrt{n^3 - 1} \right)$**

I honestly have no idea as to how to approach both these problems. By "observation" I feel like both would diverge, but they both actually converge. Any help would be appreciated.

Also, I would like to know how to approach series with logarithms and square roots in general. I can't think of what method could be used for these types of series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

For the first note that

$$\ln (1 + \frac{1}{n^2})\sim \frac{1}{n^2}$$

and for the second

$$\sqrt{n^3} - \sqrt{n^3 - 1}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^3} + \sqrt{n^3 - 1}}\sim \frac1{2n^{\frac32}}$$

then refer for to limit comparison test.

Comment: Good, glad you fixed your answer to the second

Comment: Oh, converting the second one to a fraction is a great idea. As for the first series, can't I just use the comparison test with $\frac{1}{n^2}$ rather than using the limit comparison test?

Comment: pinklemonade:  the current hint for the second can be derived by multiplying  $\sqrt{n^3} - \sqrt{n^3 -1}$ by $\frac{\sqrt{n^3} + \sqrt{n^3 - 1}}{\sqrt{n^3} + \sqrt{n^3 - 1}}$

Comment: @pinklemonade yes you can use that $\log(1+x)<x$ but why not limit comparison test? It is very effective to evaluate series convergence; for the second of course limit comaprison test is the better one

Comment: Oh yes, I know. But that is essentially converting it to a fraction, which is easier to work with for me.

Comment: @gimusi: you're right, i don't know why I have something against the limit comparison test. I need to get used to using it. Thank you so much for your help! I might be posting more questions over the next few minutes if that's okay. :P

Comment: @pinklemonade You only need to calculate a limit for which you already know the result by the preliminar asymptotic analysis which you can also do very roughly and then adjust formally and rigorously by the limit.